# List of labels for AWS Rekognition

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm trying to use AWS Rekognition to get some information about the objects in a scene (photo). I'm only interested in specific labels which are provided in a database. Therefore I need to know the exact names of the labels. I'm using the [DetectLabels](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/latest/dg/API_DetectLabels.html) API call.

However, I can't find a list of label names, AWS Rekognition provides. The [developer guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/latest/dg/what-is.html) only provides some fragments of possible responses. And the only thing the CLI help provides is:

```
         Name -> (string)
            The name (label) of the object.
```

Does anyone know where to find a complete list?

Answer (score 1):

There seems no official list of labels available but there is a hint in the [Q & A](https://aws.amazon.com/rekognition/faqs/), quote:

> **Q: What types of labels does Amazon Rekognition support?**
>
> Rekognition supports thousands of labels belonging to common
>   categories including, but not limited to:
>
> ```
> People and Events: ‘Wedding’, ‘Bride’, ‘Baby’, ‘Birthday Cake’, ‘Guitarist’, etc.
> Food and Drink: ‘Apple’, ‘Sandwich’, ‘Wine’, ‘Cake’, ‘Pizza’, etc.
> Nature and Outdoors: ‘Beach’, ‘Mountains’, ‘Lake’, ‘Sunset’, ‘Rainbow’, etc.
> Animals and Pets: ‘Dog’, ‘Cat’, ‘Horse’, ‘Tiger’, ‘Turtle’, etc.
> Home and Garden: ‘Bed’, ‘Table’, ‘Backyard’, ‘Chandelier’, ‘Bedroom’, etc.
> Sports and Leisure: ‘Golf’, ‘Basketball’, ‘Hockey’, ‘Tennis’, ‘Hiking’, etc.
> Plants and Flowers: ‘Rose’, ‘Tulip’, ‘Palm Tree’, ‘Forest’, ‘Bamboo’, etc.
> Art and Entertainment: ‘Sculpture’, ‘Painting’, ‘Guitar’, ‘Ballet’, ‘Mosaic’, etc.
> Transportation and Vehicles: ‘Airplane’, ‘Car’, ‘Bicycle’, ‘Motorcycle’, ‘Truck’, etc.
> Electronics: ‘Computer’, ‘Mobile Phone’, ‘Video Camera’, ‘TV’, ‘Headphones’, etc.
> ```

Amazon seems to update the list of labels constantly according to the Q & A, quote:

> **Q: I can’t find the label I need. How do I request a new label?**
>
> Please send us your requests through AWS Customer Support. Amazon
>   Rekognition continuously expands its catalog of labels based on
>   customer feedback.

Btw: a list of labels concering unsafe content can be found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/latest/dg/moderation.html).